# Showing that a function's Taylor series converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Define
$$\begin{align*}
    f(t) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{j}
     t^j
    &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \binom{2j}{j} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}
      {2^{2j} (2j-1)} t^j \\
    &= -\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(2j)!}{(j!)^2} \frac{1}
      {2^{2j} (2j-1)} t^j \\
    &= 1 - \sum_{j=1}^\infty c_j t^j
   \end{align*}$$
How do I show that this series converge uniformly to $\sqrt{1-t}$ on $(-1,1)$? It is given that Taylor's theorem and any properties regarding holomorphic functions cannot be used. I have tried the following:

The numbers $(c_j)_{j=0}^\infty$ can be defined recursively
$$ c_0 = -1, \hspace{5mm}
    c_{j+1} = c_j\frac{(2j+1)(2j+2)}{(j+1)^2}
     \frac{2j - 1}{4 (2(j+1) - 1)}
    = c_j\frac{2j - 1}{2j+2}
   $$
Define $f_m = \sum_{j=0}^m (-1)^j\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{j} t^j = 1 - \sum_{j=0}^m c_j t^j$ to be the partial sums. By the Weierstrass M test(Or ratio test if possible), $f_m$ converges uniformly and absolutely(trivial) on $(-1,1)$(How do I show this?), and so does its derivative $- \sum_{j=0}^\infty (j+1)c_j t^j$. Then the relationship between $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ can be established, so $f = \sqrt{1-t}$. (This is another part I'm having trouble with)

Comment: It is a well known result that a power series converges uniformly on every compact set with in its radius of convergence!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a binomial series $(a = 1/2)$ with general term

$$c_j = (-1)^j\frac{a(a-1) \ldots (a-j+1)}{j!}t^j.$$

Note that,

$$\lim_{j \to \infty}\frac{|c_{j+1}|}{|c_j|}= \lim_{j \to \infty}\frac{|a-j|}{j+1}|t| \\ =\lim_{j \to \infty}\frac{|a/j-1|}{1 + 1/j}|t| \\ = |t|.$$

Hence, the series converges for $|t| < 1$ and as a power series converges uniformly on any compact subinterval of $(-1,1).$